# Send selection from Excel by email as attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using this Macro to send the Workbook as attachment (Book1.xlsx)

```
Sub Macro2_SendByEMail()

' Copy the sheet(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy

' Send Email
With ActiveWorkbook
.SendMail Recipients:=Array("address@company.com", "address2@company"), Subject:="Addresses [" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy") & "]"
.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

End Sub
```

But I cannot find out how to edit the code so that I **send only the first three columns of the workbook**...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Think you'll need to use the Email library, presumably Outlook, and build the `.Body` of the message.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this out:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2_SendByEMail()

' Copy the sheet(1)
    Dim my_range    As Range
    Dim l_row       As Long

    l_row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Set my_range = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(l_row, 3))
    End With

    my_range.Copy

    ' Send Email
    With ActiveWorkbook
    .SendMail Recipients:=Array("address@company.com", "address2@company"), Subject:="Addresses [" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy") & "]"
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

The idea is that you take the last row of the used range in the first sheet, and based on it you define the selection to copy.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I think the problem is in the 'Send Email part, there is still "With ActiveWorkbook" where as it should probably be something like "With ActiveSelection" Plus I don't mind if the range is the whole 3 columns...

Comment: [`SendMail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821053.aspx) is a `Workbook` object method that _"Sends the workbook by using the installed mail system"_. So you can use it only to send an entire workbook. Otherwise you'll have to use the Outlook object model

Comment: Could be, I just made a vba code, selecting the first 3 columns, not taking care of the rest, cos I do not have set outlook here.